# How do I move from one ui-sortable to another in Angular?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

Someone put together a good fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/ about using angular-ui with jqueryui sortable to get a good sortable effect.

How do you move items between two sortable lists? I updated the jsfiddle to show an example http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/893/

How do I drag from `list1` (which has `['one','two','three','four','five','six']`) into `list2` (which has `['A','B','C','D','E','F']`)? For example, I want to drag 'one' into `list2` and thus get `['one','A','B','C','D','E','F']` and leave `list1` as `['two','three','four','five','six']`

A live example (but not using Angular) is Chris Ramon's http://minitrello.meteor.com 
Each is a separate sortable list, but I can move items from one to the other.

Use case? Chris' minitrello is a good one, although I am after sorting people into groups. I will present 3 lists: unassigned, groupA, groupB. The user can drag a person from unassigned into groupA, or groupB, or move them between groups, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ui-sortable directive to connect two list you need to use "connectWith" property:

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFfLF/1/)</kbd>

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" ng:model="list" class="group">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" ng:model="list2" class="group">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list2" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <div ng:repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
    <div ng:repeat="item in list2">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

    $scope.list2 = ["7", "8", "9"];

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        update: function(e, ui) {
                   },
        receive: function(e, ui) {

        },
        connectWith: ".group",
        axis: 'y'
    };
```

});

Comment: I had figured it out, but your answer is correct, I will give it credit.

Comment: Do you also know the secret to dragging to an empty list? I cannot get it to accept or have a placeholder. Question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976018/how-do-i-drag-to-an-empty-connected-list-using-angular-ui

Comment: I have replied your Answer in your newer post, check it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had missed `connectWith` option passable to ui-sortable.

Here is the updated jsfiddle, works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/894/

Comment: I reviewed your jsfiddle and sometimes I have a problem with model-view synchronization: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9067ez06lobatlt/1.png Do you know what the problem is?