# How do I drag to an empty connected list using angular-ui?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

As a follow-up to [How do I move from one ui-sortable to another in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975556/how-do-i-move-from-one-ui-sortable-to-another-in-angular/18975771)

If I have 2 connected lists, and one of the lists is empty, how do I actually drop onto it? Again looking at http://minitrello.meteor.com he has a placeholder created even in an empty list. How do I replicate that so that when

`list1 = [];
list2 = ['A','B','C']`

I can actually drop onto `list1`? Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/894/

EDIT: Cleaner fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/897/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your List is empty then also you need to create an empty Li

I have added one List in each List

```
<li ng-show="list1.length==0">&nbsp;</li>

<li ng-show="list2.length==0">&nbsp;</li>
```

Below is the working Demo

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/hKYWr/898/)</kbd>

**Template code:**

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <div style="float:left; margin:5px;">
        <h3>list1</h3>
    <ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" class="connectedList" ng:model="list1">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list1" class="item">{{item}}</li>
        <li ng-show="list1.length==0">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin:5px;">
    <h3>list2<h3>
    <ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" class="connectedList" ng:model="list2">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list2" class="item">{{item}}</li>
         <li ng-show="list2.length==0">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <hr />
    <div>list1: {{list1 | json}}</div>
    <div>list2: {{list2 | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW it gets really messed up if you put the blank item *before* the actual list.

Comment: Why is that actually necessary? minitrello didn't require it, nor do any of the actual jQui examples, see http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists It has three lists, and the right one is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's a similarly 'hacky' solution to the accepted answer but you can also add some padding(top/bottom) on to your lists to handle this problem.

e.g.

```
<ul style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7vw64z12/1/) for evidence!

This suggests the problem is that an empty list provides no 'target' to drop on.

Setting a min-height works just as well too.

Answer (score 1):

A solution i used was just to set min-height to the connected list

```
.connectedList {
  min-height: 10px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/2367/